# MySQLdump in php, I need it to dump in a specific directory

Tags: php, mysql

I run a script in one of my php files that dumps a specific database which works fine, but it puts the created file in the directory where the scripts is called. How can I make it to store the file in a specific directory? (e.g /blahblah/backups)

Here's the code (the connection code is not included but you get the idea)

```
system("mysqldump -h $pdb_server -u $pdb_user -p$pdb_pwd $pdb_name > $backupfile");
```

could I just add

```
/path/to/output/$backupfile
```

Comment: is't `$backupfile` what you want? just write full path to your directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the Path before the command:

```
system("cd /path/to/output/$backupfile; mysqldump -h $pdb_server -u $pdb_user -p$pdb_pwd $pdb_name > $backupfile");
```

or

```
system("mysqldump -h $pdb_server -u $pdb_user -p$pdb_pwd $pdb_name > /path/to/output/$backupfile");
```

Comment: Thanks. Would CD change the directory on unix, windows and mac servers or is t server specific? Wouldn't be better to add the path right before the filename in this case $backupfile?

Comment: Sorry i have forgotten the second solution. Then pipe the dump direct to the path its better.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. My other two questions didn't really have acceptable answers so this is the first one.